# La base de datos no se actualiza (SQlite Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de SQlitel , he conseguido hacer funcionar el Quiz perfectamente pero no puedo actualizar la base de datos sin desistalar, se que falta algo en el upgrade pero no se el que , algun alma amable me ayuda? gracias!!!

```js
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private String packageName;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String db_name = "quiz_db2.db";

    
    public static final String TBL_CATEGORY = "tbl_category";
    public static final String TBL_SUB_CATEGORY = "tbl_subCategory";
    public static final String TBL_QUESTION = "questions_list";
    
    public static String TBL_LEVEL = "tbl_level";

    
    ....


    private String db_path;
    private static int db_version = 5;
    Context con;


   ...
   
   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        

    }

   

   .....


    ....

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        


    }

    
   
}
```

(estoy cambiando la version de la base de datos pero aun asi nada )

Comment: Si desarrollas en Android Studio debes usar el LogCat, que error se muestra? que operacion tratas de realizar? de hecho no veo se cree ninguna tabla en onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar la base de datos la versiòn de tu compilado debe tener una versiòn mayor a la anterior:

```
private static int db_version = 6;
```

Al actualizar tu base de datos el mètodo `onUpgrade()` es llamado

Comment: Que deberia añadir en el onUpgrade? subo la version pero aun asi no hace nada

Comment: En onUpgrade solo si deseas modificar la estructura de la base de datos, deseas modificarla en la nueva versiòn?